# How to change the owner of a SQL Server table from domain\username to dbo?

Tags: sql-server, dbo

When I create a table, the owner is always domain\username instead of dbo. For example, domain\username.tablename I know how how to change it to dbo but what should I change in the configuration level to make sure that when I create a table, the default owner is dbo. like dbo.tablename ?

Thanks

Comment: When you create the table append the dbo in front of it like this:  Create Table.. dbo.TableName

Comment: Did you try to set the default schema for that user?

Comment: If you specify the schema (which you really should be when referencing objects) this problem disappears.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `DEFAULT SCHEMA` via the Object Explorer

```
Security > Users > {Your User}
```

---

```
{right-click} > Properties
```

Then on the General Tab set Default schema

[image]

Comment: Hi John, I tried that but the dbo  remains the default. Do i need to start the SQL server ? Thanks

Comment: @JoieTamayo Should not be necessary

Comment: @JoieTamayo It dawned on me that may be expecting already created tables to be renamed to dbo.   Do as above, any new table would be dbo.   Then to change existing take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: Yes, but I would like to change the default. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done using the T-SQL statement below:

```
ALTER USER [Domain\UserName] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

- In the Object Explorer, expand your database node, go to "Security" folder and expend that node too.
- You will see "Users" folder, expend that node too to see the users.
- Right click on your user
- Click propertise from the menu appears.
- In general tab, you will see "Default Schema", click on the button "..." on the right
- Select "dbo" schema and click "OK" button.

Now, try to create a new table.

Comment: Hi Sami, that's what i did and it's always dbo. Thanks